How can I solve the displaying Ukrainian Cyrillic symbols in custom fonts?
I have a problem with displaying the characters of the Ukrainian alphabet in custom fonts.
Details:
I had a custom Cyrillic font (Latin+Cyrillic), which did not include the Ukrainian letters І, Ї, Є, Ґ.
The necessary characters were added using FontForge. After saving (OTF format) and reinstalling, everything worked fine (in particular, Photoshop displayed the necessary symbols).
When copying the font file to another PC, russian Cyrillic characters are left (basic Cyrillic + Ы Ъ Э Ё), and Ukrainian characters are not displayed.
Re-opening in FontForge showed that the characters are still there.
Why did they stop showing up and how can I fix it?
Additional Information
Previous device:
Windows 10 Pro
Windows display language Russian
Ukrainian Language Pack - Installed
Basic typing Installed
Adobe Photoshop 21.2.1
New device:
Windows 11 Pro
Windows display language English
Ukrainian Language Pack - Installed
Basic typing Installed
Adobe Photoshop 22.5.5

In Adobe Photoshop 22.5.5:
✓ Enable Type Layer Glyph Alternates
✓ World-ready layout
Not sure if these two parameters are necessary, but checked to see if anything would change. No result.
In Notepad (no Ukrainian Cyrillic symbols, no Russian Cyrillic symbols for custom font):
Tried to change encoding of the file. No result.
